# Ruby attr_accessor wrapper returning nil.

Tags: ruby, transpose, attr-accessor

I have a simple class and am transposing a two dimensional array like so:

```
class Group
  attr_accessor :group_array
  def initialize
    @group_array = []
  end

  ...

  def shuffle_groups!
    new_groups = group_array.transpose
    group_array = new_groups
  end

end
```

However, when I try to set the new group array in one line like so:

```
def shuffle_groups!
    group_array = group_array.transpose
end
```

I get:

```
undefined method `transpose' for nil:NilClass
```

Why does this not work?

Comment: let me understand - you run the same code with the first implementation (and it passes), and the seconds implementation (and it fails)?

Comment: Yes, when I set the local variable it works, but when I try to set group_array to group_array it does not.

Comment: that doesn't make much sense, since `group_array.transpose` is the first thing to run in both methods... could you add `puts group_array` before each implementation?

Comment: Yes, when I puts out the variable I see it (e.g. a 2D array that contains the objects I expect).  But still get undefined method transpose for nil:NilClass

Comment: Also, I should note that when I do ```group_array = @group_array.transpose``` it works.

Comment: how about if you write `puts group_array.transpose`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make it clear to the interpreter you are calling the accessor method, and not creating a local variable.

```
class Group

  attr_accessor :group_array

  def initialize
    @group_array = [%w(1 2 3), %w(4 5 6)]
  end

  def shuffle_groups!
    new_groups = self.group_array.transpose
    self.group_array = new_groups
  end

  def shuffle_groups_2!
    self.group_array = self.group_array.transpose
  end

end

g = Group.new
p g.group_array
# [["1", "2", "3"], ["4", "5", "6"]]
g.shuffle_groups!
p g.group_array
# [["1", "4"], ["2", "5"], ["3", "6"]]
g.shuffle_groups_2!
p g.group_array
# [["1", "2", "3"], ["4", "5", "6"]]
```

Both of those methods work fine.

Comment: why are you referencing self instead of just using the instance variable `@group_array`.

Comment: Personally?  I always use the instance variable.  I'm not here to dictate style though. :)

Comment: I do use the ```@group_array``` typically.  I figured it was something to do with local variable confusion.